# Different vsize for first page

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Is it possible to alter the vsize for the first page?

I tried this:

```
\vsize=20cm
\def\pagebody{%
   \ifnum\pageno=1%
     \advance\vsize by -8cm%
     \vskip13cm\vbox to \vsize{\boxmaxdepth=\maxdepth \pagecontents}%
   \else
     \vskip5cm\vbox to \vsize{\boxmaxdepth=\maxdepth \pagecontents}%
   \fi}%
```

But it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The TeXbook p. 114 reads:

> Since `\vsize`, `\maxdepth`, and `\topskip` are parameters, you can change them at any time; what happens if you do? Well, TeX salts away the values of `\vsize` and `\maxdepth` when it prints the “`%%` line,” i.e., when the first box or insertion occurs on the current page; subsequent changes to those two parameters have no effect until the next current page is started.

So, if you want a `\vsize` change to affect the current page, it has to occur before the first box or insertion has been added. In your case, you are trying to change it in the `\output` routine (since this is where `\pagebody` is used), which is way too late: the page body has already been fully boxed when the `\output` routine is called—it is in `\box255`, so it is clearly too late to hope changing its `\vsize`.

What you can do is initialize `\vsize` to `12cm` at the beginning of the document (before the first box or insertion has been added) and change its value *for subsequent pages* from within the `\output` routine. This has to be done using `\global` since the `\output` routine is executed inside a group.

```latex
\vsize=12cm

\def\pagebody{%
   \ifnum\pageno=1
     \vskip 13cm\vbox to \vsize{\boxmaxdepth=\maxdepth \pagecontents}%
     \global\advance\vsize by 8cm
   \else
     \vskip 5cm\vbox to \vsize{\boxmaxdepth=\maxdepth \pagecontents}%
   \fi}%

\newcount\mycount

\def\repeattext#1#2{%
  \mycount=#1
  \loop
  \ifnum \mycount >0
  \advance\mycount by -1
  #2%
  \repeat
}

Foo bar \repeattext{2200}{foo bar }
\bye
```

[image: screenshots]